# Why does `of(undefined) emit, but `of()` does not?

Tags: rxjs

I found this working on some unit tests. Can anyone explain why this works this way? It feels like a bug to me.

Here my test is passing when it shouldn't because the observable isn't emitting.

[image]

Changing `of()` to `of(undefined)` causes the test to fail correctly.

[image]

I'd expect `of()` and `of(undefined)` to be equivalent. Anyone know a reason why they aren't?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because the parameters of the `of()` method is defined as a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#Description) `...args`, so they get combined into an array, so an empty array get passed along.

[rxjs/src/internal/observable/of.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/259e5cd2e8149bc5db14cc0216afec7131e8aa11/src/internal/observable/of.ts#L99)

```
export function of<T>(...args: Array<T | SchedulerLike>): Observable<T> {
  let scheduler = args[args.length - 1] as SchedulerLike;
  if (isScheduler(scheduler)) {
    args.pop();
    return scheduleArray(args as T[], scheduler);
  } else {
    return fromArray(args as T[]);
  }
}
```

`of(undefined)` turns into `[undefined]` in which case `undefined` is emitted.

`of()` turns into `[]` in which case nothing is emitted.

As far as being a bug, I think it's working as they intend:

> @param {...T} values A comma separated list of arguments you want to be emitted

From that, I'd say, if you don't pass anything, nothing should be emitted.

Comment: I have no doubt it's as intended. It just seems really weird that you can invoke `of()` and have nothing happen. It seems if you're invoking the function, you're expecting _something_ to happen. And if no argument is provided, emitting undefined seems pretty natural. Though I'm probably just wishing Observables worked more like Promises.

Comment: "and have nothing happen" - `of()` typically does 3 things: 1) create observable 2) emit provided values 3) complete observable.  It is still performing items 1 and 3.  And arguably item2.

Comment: As BizzyBox mentioned it does something. A promise will never emit a value if you do not call .then. A Observable.create will never emit a value if you do not call .next. So does of work. If the function does not get any value as param it does not emit any value. I think it is a very predictable api and an empty of has a sense: observable that completes without any value emit.